# How can I define type for a component as an icon in svelte, typescript?

Tags: typescript, icons, svelte, sveltekit

I am trying to build a navigation menu in SvelteKit.

```
const navigationMenu: { path: string; label: string; icon:??? }[] = [
        {
            path: '/',
            label: 'Home',
            icon: Home
        },
```

I want to render the icon in each navigation item like this:

```
 <ul>
            {#each navigationMenu as item}
                <li class:active={item.path === $page.url.pathname}>
                    <a href={item.path}>
                        <svelte:component
                            this={item.icon}
                            focusable="false"
                            aria-hidden="true"
                            size={26}
                            strokeWidth={2}
                        />
                        {item.label}
                    </a>
                </li>
            {/each}
        </ul>
```

I could not figure out what to pass typescript type for `icon`

```
const navigationMenu: { path: string; label: string; icon:??? }[] = []
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question [changed over time](https://github.com/sveltejs/language-tools/issues/486).

In 2023, to correctly type custom component, you can use [Component Type](https://github.com/sveltejs/language-tools/issues/486).

```js
import type { ComponentType } from 'svelte';
...
const navigationMenu: { path: string; label: string; icon: ComponentType }[] = [
        {
            path: '/',
            label: 'Home',
            icon: Home
        },
        ...
]
...
```

Comment: I want to specify that is an icon component. can i do it in sveltekit?

Comment: @Yilmaz Could you elaborate a little more on what do you mean by icon component? Isn't it a normal svelte component? If it isn't, what is the difference between a svelte component and the icon component that you mentioned?

Answer (score 0):

using `lucid-svelte`:

```
import { type Icon } from 'lucide-svelte';
import type { ComponentType } from 'svelte';
```

then define the type for icon like this:

```
const navigationMenu: { path: string; 
                        label: string; 
                        icon: ComponentType<Icon> }[] = []
```